# add json object to jsonarray android / Java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm getting a JSONarray that has this values:

```
[{"id":"1","type":"7"},
 {"id":"2","type":"6"},
 {"id":"5","type":"5"},
 {"id":"6","type":"4"}]
```

and so on.

The thing is that I want to write a new array from this one that has an extra field that is the multipilication of "id" by "type". Something like this :

```
[{"id":"1","type":"7","result","7"},
 {"id":"2","type":"6","result","12"}]
```

and so on.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's GSON package and it's internal JSON implementation as follows.

Supposing that you have your jsonArray pre-filled:

```
JsonArray values = what_ever_your_values_are; (if you define you data stream i can guide you further)
JsonArray newJsonArray = new JsonArray();

for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++){
   JsonObject temp = new JsonObject();
   temp.addProperty("id",values.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsString());
   temp.addProperty("type",values.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("type").getAsString());
   int result = Integer.parseInt(values.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsInt()) * 
                Integer.parseInt(values.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("type").getAsInt()); //for the sake of simplicity
   temp.addProperty("result",String.valueOf(result));
   newJsonArray.add(temp);
}
```

Comment: I'll give a shot and report back !